# How to send an event to Windows Event Collector via C# - WSMan

Tags: c#, event-log

Assuming Windows Event Collector is set up on my server machine, how can I send custom events to the collector using c# with(or without) Ws-Management protocol, namely WSMan class on system32/WSmAuto.dll?

Preferably without setting anything on client machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var appLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        appLog.Source = "YOUR APPLICATION NAME";
        appLog.WriteEntry("my event text", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

Comment: This is for direct logging. For remote logging, I can add machine name as a parameter but there are security issues in this technique.

Comment: Well, you answered your own question: add the machine name! Security issues have nothing to do with C# code, but you have to have access rights set correctly. I am not sure, but I think you do not need admin rights. If you cannot set security settings correctly (due to for instance corporate policies, or if comptuers are not part of domain) I would suggesting making a small server on the target that has only one remoting interface that does exactly the code above. But security is always there, it should be!

Comment: "Windows Event Collector" is in a way that "small server". My aim is to minimize the effort required for the user to achieve remote logging, which would be the best if nothing extra installed on the server machine. I have already Diagnostics.EventLog in my mind. What I am trying to learn about the alternatives and comparing the techniques according to security, usability, flexibility on users' perspective.